# Data transfer between application outside profile and inside profile in Android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, mdm, data-transfer, android-for-work

Question related to **Android for Work**.
My application was a device Admin privileged app and now I have modified the code which creates a managed work profile and sets itself as the profile owner.

The question is, if I *upgrade* my application, it becomes a profile owner from device admin. Now there will be **two copies** of my application, one outside the profile and one inside (badged version).

Is there a way if I need to transfer some data from the personal space app to the work profile app (badged version)?

Answer (score 3):

The DevicePolicyManager class implements a the [addCrossProfileIntentFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#addCrossProfileIntentFilter(android.content.ComponentName,%20android.content.IntentFilter,%20int)) method for explicitly allowing Intents to be sent from the managed profile to the primary user profile.

```
public void addCrossProfileIntentFilter (ComponentName admin, IntentFilter filter, int flags)
```

Although

> Called by the profile owner of a managed profile so that some intents sent in the managed profile can also be resolved in the parent, or vice versa. **Only activity intents are supported.**